# Inconsistent mxClient.isBrowserSupported() value between MS Edge 12 and Edge 13

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I tried running `mxClient.isBrowserSupported()` in MS Edge 12 and 13 using [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com)

The result is that it returns `false` in MS Edge 12 but returns `true` in MS Edge 13.

I digged a little bit deeper into the code and they have these snippet.

```
IS_SVG: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox/') >= 0 || // FF and Camino
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Iceweasel/') >= 0 || // Firefox on Debian
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Seamonkey/') >= 0 || // Firefox-based
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Iceape/') >= 0 || // Seamonkey on Debian
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Galeon/') >= 0 || // Gnome Browser (old)
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Epiphany/') >= 0 || // Gnome Browser (new)
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('AppleWebKit/') >= 0 || // Safari/Google Chrome
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Gecko/') >= 0 || // Netscape/Gecko
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera/') >= 0 || // Opera
    (document.documentMode != null && document.documentMode >= 9), // IE9+
```

I tried outputting navigator.userAgent in MS Edge 12 and 13

MS Edge 12

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64, x64)
```

MS Edge 13

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64, x64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
```

I don't know why the user agent for MS Edge 12 is different. Is it because I am using [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com)?

Comment: What version of mxGraph is this? Any version released after the production version of Edge 12 worked correctly on it, so it's that's the case the problem is with the user agent BrowserStack is providing. IS_SVG is separate to whether the browser is supported, there are different things.

Comment: I think you might be right. I am using `3.1.2.1` which was released on January 5, 2015. The first version of Edge 13 came out around September 18, 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an older version of MxGraph(`3.1.2.1`) which does not have proper checks for MS Edge browsers yet.

Upgrading to the new version solved the problem.